# Stop condition For in python

Tags: python

I have a text file containing lines like the following:

```
3.8,5.4,1.4,12.6,3.5,1.8,7.9,yes
3.4,5.4,1.4,12.6,2.5,7.0,5.9,yes
3.8,5.4,1.7,12.6,5.5,8.8,4.9,yes
3.9,5.4,1.1,12.6,2.5,1.2,1.9,no
```

I’m trying to make that file into a list with the following code:

```
datos=[]
with open('archivo.data') as f:
    for linea in f:
        datos.append([int(n) for n in linea.split(",") ])
```

How can I convert to int only until the penultimate column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Original Contents of "archivo.data" before edit

```
3,5,1,12,2,1,1,5,4,4,yes
1,11,2,8,4,12,4,9,1,2,no
1,5,1,11,1,12,1,8,2,4,yes
2,3,1,7,1,10,1,9,2,9,yes
2,12,3,7,2,6,4,13,2,7,no
```

You can use slicing and negative indexing.

```
res = []
with open('archivo.data') as file:
    for line in file:
        split_line = line.strip().split(',')
        res.append([int(i) for i in split_line[:-1]])
        res[-1].append(split_line[-1])

print(res)
```

Output

```
[[3, 5, 1, 12, 2, 1, 1, 5, 4, 4, 'yes'], [1, 11, 2, 8, 4, 12, 4, 9, 1, 2, 'no'], [1, 5, 1, 11, 1, 12, 1, 8, 2, 4, 'yes'], [2, 3, 1, 7, 1, 10, 1, 9, 2, 9, 'yes'], [2, 12, 3, 7, 2, 6, 4, 13, 2, 7, 'no']]
```

Edit : The original question was edited to include floating values in the file, this answer was posted before that edit, to make this work for the new edit, follow the suggestion from the [other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/66594519/12502959) to convert to float and then to int

Answer (score 2):

You can use slicing to ignore the last element of `split()`:

```
datos=[]
with open('Odata.txt') as f:
    for linea in f:
        datos.append([int(float(n)) for n in linea.split(",")[:-1]])
print(datos)
```

Also, note that you need to first convert to `float` and they can't be directly converted to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

```
datos=[]
with open('archivo.data') as f:
    for linea in f:
        datos.append([(int(n) if isdigit(n) else n) for n in linea.split(",") ])
```

Comment: I think it needs to be `n.isdigit()` or `str.isdigit(n)`

Answer (score 0):

```
datos=[]
with open('archivo.data') as f:
    for linea in f:
      for n in linea.split(","):
        if (n == "yes\n" or n == "no\n" or n=="yes" or n=="no"):
          datos.append(n)            
        else:
          datos.append(int(float(n)))
print(datos)
```

Output -

```
[3, 5, 1, 12, 3, 1, 7, 'yes\n', 3, 5, 1, 12, 2, 7, 5, 'yes\n', 3, 5, 1, 12, 5, 8, 4, 'yes\n', 3, 5, 1, 12, 2, 1, 1, 'no']
```